# In-app Purchase Loop Hole

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase

OK so have a problem with the whole in-app purchase review process and hope someone can shed some light/experience on it.

We have a project which is a magazine for the ipad. Each issue requires an in-app purchase before it is downloaded. The issues are served from an XML feed when a new one is published.

The problem is, how can we have Apple review an in-app purchase without displaying the new issue. They wont be able to see it in the live binary. If we publish the issue we have to say "unavailable", which looks extremely unprofessional to the customer, until the in-app purchase is reviewed.

We dont want to have to publish a new binary each time a new issue is published as thats a pointless exercise for the customer

Thanks, any suggestions apart from change message to "coming soon" would be apprciated. The only other thought we had is a flag in the app settings which displays "unavailable issues"

Answer (score 1):

If you login to your iOS developer account, you'll find this **Getting Started with in App Purchase** pdf file, which has information that you'll need in your setting up with your iAP item.

Specifically, I think what you need is an item belongs to the category named **Subscriptions**. This should solve your problem.

Comment: I will reread that doc, but its not a subscription as such, they buy each issue adhoc

Comment: then when you submit your iAP item, can you use a relatively abstract concept such as **buying a service to have one and only one of this magazine's issues delivered to the iDevice (Consumable)** ?

Comment: it seems a bit of a hoop, surely thats not how the likes of wired etc handle it?!?!

Answer (score 0):

You can use consumable purchases, i.e. right to download 1 article. 5 purchases - 5 articles.
Or, give a user subscription for month or so.

Comment: I want them to purchase each issue once, which they can then redownload at any point, I dont want it to be consumed either

Comment: You save in your database that customer bought that specific issue, and give him the ability to re-download it later. And, btw, you will always be able to add additional issues, and new in-app purchases, and populate the list of available downloads in your program dynamically, so this will not require re-compilation.

Comment: But if the customer deletes the app the acknowledgement of payment is lost

Comment: You can restore them from Apple, and, you can restore them via user's account on site or via unique iPhone identifier.

Comment: Are apps out there that work this way? I'm really curious cause this would need a mandatory registration for payments... you're not getting rejected for this?

Answer (score 0):

You could always just keep some kind of "sample" issue available for the purposes of the user demoing the software.

That, or a few select pages from the active issue could be specified as "demo pages", as in they would be viewable from a demo version of the software.

Comment: We have a demo version but we cant provide that to apple to use that for review purposes, when all they are reviewing is an inapp purchase only, they are expecting it in the live binary